# What is the equivalent of ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues for DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is the equivalent of ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues for DbContext?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is no equivalent. You can either get the ObjectContext with...

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues(...)
```

...or use a similar method of `DbEntityEntry`:

```
 myDbContext.Entry(originalEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(changedEntity);
```

`originalEntity` represents the object before the change (usually fetched from database before you update). It must be attached to the context. `changedEntity` represents the entity with the same key which has been changed.

This second approach is probably closely related to the `ObjectStateEntry.ApplyCurrentValues` method of EF 4.0
.