# How to get the selected value from combo box in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am trying to get the DepartmentId after selecting the item in combo box and then assign it to the nameTextBox.Text. But when I run the program it gives Null Reference Exception.

```
        var deptList = dr.ReadAllDepartment();            
        departmentCombobox.DisplayMemberPath = "DepartmentName";
        departmentCombobox.SelectedValuePath = "DepartmentId";
        departmentCombobox.ItemsSource = deptList;
        nameTextBox.Text = departmentCombobox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: You could use SetValues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807622/what-is-the-equivalent-of-objectcontext-applycurrentvalues-for-dbcontext

Answer (score 0):

SelectedValue is null because there is no selected value.  The user didn't select a value in the brief moment between when you set the ItemSource and when you tried to access SelectedValue.

Answer (score 0):

At some point `departmentCombobox.SelectedValue` is `null` and the `ToString()` is being called on `null`.

You can use the `?` operator;
you can also select the first item on the ComboBox before trying to access it:

```
var deptList = dr.ReadAllDepartment();            
departmentCombobox.DisplayMemberPath = "DepartmentName";
departmentCombobox.SelectedValuePath = "DepartmentId";
departmentCombobox.ItemsSource = deptList;

departmentCombobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
nameTextBox.Text = departmentCombobox.SelectedValue?.ToString();
```